# Добавить заголовок WININET

Tags: winapi, header, http, c++, wininet

Добрый день, требуется добавить заголовок к запросу. Возвращает false. Подскажите, где может быть ошибка

```
wchar_t *Range = L"Range: bytes=0-600";
bool range = HttpAddRequestHeaders(session, Range, wcslen(Range), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
handle = InternetOpenUrlW(session, url, 0, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
```

Вообще этот функционал требуется для докачки файла после дисконекта и для многопоточного скачивания файла. Реализован на С#, а вот в WINAPI появилась проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, Вы не учли, что:

> Each header must be terminated by a CR/LF (carriage return/line feed) pair

Ну а если и нет, стоит еще проверить, что вернула `GetLastError` после вызова `HttpAddRequestHeaders`, возможно, проблема не в заголовке, а в самом коннекте (session).